# Can not select region in cloud sql instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to create a mysql instance in cloud sql and I need Europe region. But I am not able to select region here as the dropdown is showing only one option "any". For High Availability option too, its same.
I have a project running live now, in which I created cloud sql instance with Europe region. In that project too, when I try to create a new instance now, the region option is showing like this only. Is there any policy change with GCP lately? I could not figure out what the issue is.

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uQCR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Google Chrome browser and if you are already using Chrome browser make sure that you are using the latest version.

It should be like this: [image]

If nothing has changed, the other way to create Cloud SQL instance is using the `gcloud` command in [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell) or install [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install).

**`gcloud` format :**

```
gcloud sql instances create INSTANCE_NAME --tier=MACHINE_TYPE --region=REGION
```

**`gcloud` example :**

```
gcloud sql instances create instancename1 --tier=db-n1-standard-2 --region=europe-west1
```

For more parameters setting when creating Cloud SQL instance, visit this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance#create-2nd-gen).

Comment: chrome could not help it. But your second option was awesome.